# SQL Server Management Studio - Specify Values for Template Parameters auto-generation of "Create date"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a lot of stored procedures in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

I am using the [Query -> Specify Values for Template Parameters method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx).

I wonder if someone knows how to have the Author and Create date fields automatically contain my name and the current date. At the moment I have to type them in again and again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. You could write some dynamic SQL that prints your template. You can then tell it to print GETDATE(), and your name would be stored as a variable.

You would run the code then paste the result into your window as your template.

Comment: I am still a bit green when it comes to SQL but will try to implement your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For your name, you can specify the template like below

`<Author,String,Sam Leach>`